# Push Notifications with Nodejs project without using FCM, One Signal, APN or etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to build a Node.js (Express.js) microservice project with push notification subject,
but I don't want to use FCM, APN, One Signal or other push notification services.
I want to use my own Socket.io to push notification to android/web users.

There are some features :

1.Send notifications to specific user/users

2.Send notifications to users in background (Service workers in browsers) and when the socket is disconnected.

Is it possible?

Is there a logic to solving this problem?

Answer (score -1):

It is definitely possible.

- But, however the client socket must be connected to your Node.js socket server to send the notifications.
- So you can try to implement your client socket connection to be
  connected to server every time the client device has an active internet
  connection.
- Reference to this [post](https://xtreemsolution.com/blog/How-to-make-real-time-notification-system-using-socketio-and-nodejs) for the basic
  usage of socket.io to send notifications.

Comment: How can I keep socket connection after stopping app or closing web page?

Comment: You can use service workers: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers